# how to return partial array match in inner array of mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I am showing an example of mongodb collection document structure. I have also shown my expected result while making query which i have shown.

Document Structure::

```
{ 
  _id : "132423423", 
  name : "hi_code", 
  my_entries : [ 
        { 
          e_id : "12345", 
          e_name : "f1", 
          e_posted : "2010-05-01", 
        }, 
        { 
          e_id : "12346", 
          e_name : "f2", 
          e_posted : "2010-06-01", 
        }, 
        { 
          e_id : "12346", 
          e_name : "f3", 
          e_posted : "2010-03-02", 
        } 
   ] 
}
```

Query Structure::

```
db.myCollection.find( { my_entries : { $elemMatch : { e_posted : "2010-06-01", 
e_name : "f2" } } } )
```

Expected Result::

```
{ 
  _id : "132423423", 
  name : "hi_code", 
  my_entries : [ 
        { 
          e_id : "12346", 
          e_name : "f2", 
          e_posted : "2010-06-01", 
        }
   ] 
}
```

I don't want to use map reduce for this because i am working on big database which will make it slow performance, just want to make it possible only by find query.

Answer (score 3):

Your actual result is the entire document which matches the query.

You are expecting only part of the document to be returned, but there is no way to specify that only matching array elements be returned in 2.0.

Starting with version 2.2 (next production version currently available as unstable development version 2.1) you would be able to use the aggregation framework to get back what you want in this example.

2.2 also supports [$elemMatch as a projection operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/projection/elemMatch/) - note that this will return at most **one** matching array element.

With aggregation framework you can do something like this:

```
db.myCollection.aggregate( [
     {$match : { my_entries : { $elemMatch : { e_posted : "2010-06-01", e_name : "f2" } } } },
     {$unwind : "$my_entries"},
     {$match : { my_entries : { e_posted : "2010-06-01", e_name : "f2" } } }
] )
```

This will return as many documents as there are matching entries in all my_entries arrays.  If you want to group them back you will need to add a `{$group:}` entry at the end of the pipeline.

Comment: can i solve this problem without mapreduce in mongodb version 2.0.4, using any other trick.

Comment: You can do it on the app side--match the document, and then pull out what you want after you retrieve it.

Comment: you can only get a subset of an array via the $slice operator but that requires knowing the position of the array element.

Comment: It seems not to be this feature in the version 2.2 of mongodb, does any one have relevant information to solve my problem.

Comment: in 2.2 you can use $elemMatch in the projection (second argument passed to 'find' but that will return at most one matching array element (first one).  if you want to use agg frame work, you will need to use pipeline of form $match: __ , $unwind: __ ,$match: ___ ,$group: ___

Comment: Edited answer to include comments about both 2.2 options.